# Moving an existing Django project into a virtual environment

Tags: django, virtualenv

I made the mistake of installing my Django project globally in the first instance, and I'm now trying to move into a virtual environment on the same machine.  I installed Django on the new VE, then copied the src files across.
It all appeared to work fine initially, until I removed the globally installed dependencies (crispy forms, etc) and reinstalled in the virtual environment. Obviously there is some hard-coded paths to to these dependencies somewhere as it's failing to locate the new VE installed modules, but I can't seem to find them. Is there a checklist of places I should be modifying? Thanks

> Edit: My error: I hadn't activated the virtual environment.  Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 5):

use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to output the installed packages in the requirements format. The use `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside your virtual environment for install the packages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So all I need to do is take a snapshot of the currently used tools of my python project by `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, install a virtual environment and execute the installation `pip install -r requirements.txt` based on the `requirements.txt`? Is there anything else I have to be aware of regarding my project source files, when adding a new virtual environment directory?